# Maclaurin Series expansion for $\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find Maclaurin Series expansion for $$\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^2}$$ and for what values of $x$ is the expansion valid?

The text book starts the answer with $$\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+\sum...$$
Why is $1-x^2$ taken out?

Secondly, why is the expansion not valid for all $x$? The denominator will always be greater than $0$ since $1+x^2>0 $ for all real values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^2}&=&x+\frac{1-x}{1+x^2}\\
&=&x+(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}\text{ for }\vert x\vert<1\\
&=&x+(1-x)(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-x^{10}+\cdots)\\
&=&x+1-x-x^2+x^3+x^4-x^5-x^6+x^7+x^8-x^9-x^{10}\cdots\\
&=&1-x^2+(x^3+x^4)-(x^5+x^6)+(x^7+x^8)-(x^9+x^{10})+\cdots\\
&=&1-x^2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k(x^{2k-1}+x^{2k})\text{ for }\vert x\vert<1
\end{eqnarray}
When $x=1$ the series diverges, but at $x=-1$ the series converges to $0$.

So the interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: observe that

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac1{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x^2)^k,\quad\text{when }|x|<1$$

When you had the Maclaurin series of your function evaluate it radius of convergence to know for what values of $x$ the Taylor series represent the function.

A Maclaurin series represent the function whenever the series converges locally uniformly in some neighborhood of zero.

Comment: But why was $1-x^2$ taken out in the fashion that is given in the post?

Comment: check what are the first two terms of your series following my answer

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks